# How can I POST json data from android app to Ruby on Rails server

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json, android-volley, api-design

I am trying to send json data to my RoR server so that a new object is created when the POST request is received by the server. I am really new to RoR so I am not sure how to set this up correctly.

I have been searching other posts on here for a while applying solutions to similar problems but nothing I do seems to work.

On the Rails end of things - I have a route set up specifically for this purpose.

in routes.rb

```
post '/api' => 'expenses#post_json_expense'
```

in expenses_controller.rb

```
# For creating an expense from the android app
def post_json_expense
  Expense.new(expense_params)
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def expense_params
  params.require(:expense).permit(:user_id, :amount, :category, :description)
end
```

I also turned off token authentication in case that is causing the problem.

in config/application

```
config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false
```

On the android side of things, I am using Volley to send the POST request

```
private void saveExpense () {
        // Build the URL
        String url = "https://my-project-url.herokuapp.com/api";
        Log.i("API_REQUEST", url);

        EditText etAmount = findViewById(R.id.et_amount);
        EditText etDescription = findViewById(R.id.et_description);
        EditText etCategory = findViewById(R.id.et_category);

        // Get values from the EditTexts
        double amount = Double.parseDouble(etAmount.getText().toString());
        String description = etDescription.getText().toString().trim();
        String category = etCategory.getText().toString().trim();

        // If something was entered into all of the fields
        if (amount > 0 && !description.isEmpty() && !category.isEmpty()) {


            // Convert field entries into a JSON object
            JSONObject expenseData = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject expenseObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                expenseData.put("user_id", user_id);
                expenseData.put("amount", amount);
                expenseData.put("description", description);
                expenseData.put("category", category);
                expenseObject.put("expense", expenseData);


            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT, url, expenseObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Toast.makeText(EditExpenseActivity.this, "POST Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(EditExpenseActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(EditExpenseActivity.this, "POST Unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    return params;
                }
            };

            // Make the API request
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);


        }
    }
```

I keep getting a the error response each time I try to post data to the app.
Where am I going wrong? I'm pretty new to rails is my first time trying to build an API so I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly.

Comment: your values should be under 'expense' key in post data. means expenseJson should also be added in json object on key 'expense'.

Comment: @wasipeer thanks for the response. I just edited my post to include your recommended changes - however it is still not posting successfully

Comment: can you please share the error details ?

Comment: I just know that onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) is being called because the "POST Unsuccessful" toast pops up when I am running the app. Also when I check the database on the rails server I can see that the expense isn't being added like I would like it to

Comment: what error msg you get on rails side please check the server console and share the error and try to toast error.getMessage().

Comment: I just checked the logs and the only thing relvant to my post is "2019-04-22T07:20:52.883645+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=PUT path="/api" host=cst-438-project-desktop.herokuapp.com request_id=2ca33faf-fb56-4a5b-94ef-d8ea8310dc36 fwd="12.175.87.86" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=1744 protocol=https" 


Also error.getMessage is coming up with a blank toast. 

Can you tell if my post_json_expense method is setup correctly? Because I am not very confident in it - I am wondering if that is where part of the issue is. –

Comment: first try this on your local machine it will be easy for you to track the error. After successfully running on your machine, go for the heroku server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to S.O.!

So, there's a few things that need addressing here. For starters, in your controller:

```rb
# For creating an expense from the android app
def post_json_expense
  Expense.new(expense_params)
end
```

So, first, calling `Expense.new` here will only create a new object, but it will not persist it to the database; you'll also need to call `save` to do that.

Next, you are not returning any sort of response back to the caller. Perhaps returning something like the id of the new Expense would be in order, or the expense itself. I'd suggest constructing the call like so:

```
# For creating an expense from the android app
def post_json_expense
  expense = Expense.new(expense_params)
  unless expense.save
    # TODO: Return an error status with some useful details
    # You can get some from expense.errors
    return render status: 400, json: { error: true }
  end
  # Render a JSON representation of the expense on successful save
  render json: expense.as_json
end
```

Next, on the client side, you are sending `Content-type` headers, which is good, but you could also send `Accept` headers, which clues the server as to what you expect to receive back:

```
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
  Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
  params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
  params.put("Accept", "application/json");
  return params;
}
```

Finally, you have assigned the method to the POST route on your server:

```
post '/api' => 'expenses#post_json_expense'
```

But you are calling it as a PUT from your app:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT, url, expenseObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
```

So, there is no `PUT` route at that URL, hence why the request would always fail.

Cleaning up these issues should get you a successful response.

Personally, I find using a simple utility like `curl` often helps debug these sort of communication errors, when you don't know whether the issue is the fault of an app-side coding issue or a server-side coding issue (or both). You can eliminate the variables by using something like `curl` which you can be confident works, then debug from there.

Hope this helps you along!

Comment: Very helpful post! I really appreciate that in addition to the recommended changes you also explained why things weren't working as so I could understand the issue better. The app is now posting successfully :)